# Qual è il significato di "essere un po' a terra come corredo"?

Tags: meaning, idioms

Nel romanzo *La ragazza di Bube* di Carlo Cassola ho letto:

> Finalmente mise insieme la roba che le sarebbe servita per il viaggio: due fazzoletti, un paio di mutande, il portamonete con pochi spiccioli dentro, il pettine, lo spazzolino, il dentifricio, cinque o sei nastri: solo di quelli aveva abbondanza, ma erano tutti scoloriti. Fece un fagottino, e aprì la valigia di Bube per mettercelo.
>          «Bube. Bubino.»
>          Egli si affacciò sulla porta, un po' sorpreso e contrariato di essere chiamato in quel modo.
>          «È tutta qui la tua roba?»
>          «Sì; Perchè?»
>          «Perchè allora sei anche te povero in canna» disse Mara, e rise.
>          «Eh, sì, sono un po' a terra come corredo» ammise Bube.

Non capisco il significato dell'ultima frase che dice Bube: «sono un po' a terra come corredo». Nel [Dizionario dei Modi di Dire Hoepli](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario-modi-di-dire/T/terra.shtml#1) ho trovato questa definizione:

> **essere a terra**
>
> • Fig.: versare in cattive condizioni, fisicamente, moralmente, economicamente e così via.

Quindi, immagino che la frase abbia qualcosa a che vedere col fatto di essere molto povero. Tuttavia, non so perché Bube dice «come corredo». Me lo sapreste spiegare?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Essere a terra*** non implica necessariamente il fatto di essere in difficoltà economiche o poveri.
L'espressione viene usata principalmente in senso emotivo.

- ho perso il lavoro e mi sento veramente a terra (depresso)
- la mia fidanzata mi ha lasciato e ho il morale a terra.

Nel brano il senso è economico, il corredo probabilmente  è composto da poche cose a causa  di poche disponibilità economiche.

Il termine [corredo](http://dizionari.repubblica.it/Italiano/C/corredo.php) viene comunemente usato in riferimento alla dote nuziale di una sposa ma significa anche:

> - Complesso di indumenti necessari a una persona per un certo periodo di tempo e per determinati uffici: *il c. del soldato, del collegiale, della monaca; preparare il c. del nascituro; un c. ricco, lussuoso, scarso, misero*;

(Hoepli)

Comment: Quindi significa che quello che Bube ha nella valigia è insufficiente per il viaggio che stanno per fare?

Comment: che ha poca roba, un corredo da viaggio scarso.

Comment: Capisco, grazie! Avevo letto la definizione di "corredo" nel Treccani, ma là non appare questa idea del "corredo da viaggio" (perlomeno non in modo esplicito).

Comment: Mi è venuto un dubbio riferito a questo modo d'interpretare la frase: se il corredo è quello che è scarso, non dovrebbe essere il corredo quello che è a terra invece di esserlo Bube? Cioè, questo personaggio non dovrebbe dire "il mio corredo è un po' a terra" invece di "sono un po' a terra"?

Comment: @Charo - il personaggio dice "sono un po' a terra (scarso)  'come' (per quanto riguarda il)  corredo". È un modo di dire colloquiale. Se dici che il corredo è a terra significa che è sul pavimento.